# RTD Client with 3rd party RTD Server : C#

Tags: c#, rtd

I am trying to connect custom RTD client, written in C# with 3rd party RTD server.

```
Type rtd;
Object rtdServer = null;
rtd = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ProgId","WS001");
rtdServer = Activator.CreateInstance(rtd);
```

where `WS001` is my machine name, and `ProgId` is name for RTD server. I got this error,

> Error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BA): Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID
>   {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx} from machine "WS001" failed due
>   to the following error: 800706ba "WS001".`

I am using windows 7 64 bit os.

Answer (score 0):

If `WS001` is your local machine name, then try the other overload, which doesn not take the machine name:

```
rtd = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ProgId");
```